# Removing a certain amount of lines from the end of a string in C#

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio, delete-row

So I have a project in Visual Studio with a label showing a multi-line string, and I need to remove a specific amount of lines from the end of the string to prevent the text from going out of boundaries of the label. How do I do this in C#?

EDIT | Sorry I seem to have worded my question wrong, I need to delete the lines from the beginning of the string and not the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep the first 3:

```
text = string.Join("\n", text.Split('\n').Take(3));
```

And after

> Sorry ..., I need to delete the lines from the beginning of the string and not the end.

```
var lines = text.Split('\n');
text = string.Join("\n", lines.Skip(lines.Length - 3));
```

Comment: `\n` is not a valid newline in Windows. You might want to use `Environment.NewLine`.

Comment: It (`'\n'`) usually is. But even if there are `'\r'` in play here they will be preserved.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that you store the multiline text in a variable named multiLineString and want just the first three lines.

```
multiLineString = label1.Text;

multiLineString = string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
              multiLineString.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine},  
             StringSplitOptions.None).Take(3));

label1.Text = multiLineString;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (just keep the first MAX_NUMBER_OF_LINES):

```
var lines = originalstring.Split(new [] { '\r', '\n' }); // <-- I used constansts instead of Enivronment.NewLine because I'm not sure about input format
lines = lines.Take(MAX_NUMBER_OF_LINES);
var newstring = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines);
```